# Can someone tell me "how the array function is out of bound"? And if not is the code correct?

Tags: arrays, c, function

Declare an int array numbers of length 10. Write a function void readValues(int numbers []), that read values in the range 10 to 40 from keyboard and prompt for replacement if input has values outside 10 to 40.

Write a C program with a separate function that does the circular left shift of the elements of array numbers by n position(s). The n is a positive number and should be read from the keyboard.

Here is example of input:- 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
(int n=)   5
OUTPUT :- 16 17 18 19 20 11 12 13 14 15

```
#include <stdio.h>
//We will take input of numbers from the user
void readValues(int numbers[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        int a;
        scanf("%d",&a);
        if(a>40 || a<10)
        {
            printf("Please enter a value in range:");//If user puts number greater than 40 or less than 10
            scanf("%d",&a);
            numbers[i]=a;
        }
        else
        {
            numbers[i]=a;
        }
    }
}
//now we will put conditions for reversing numbers
int reverse(int numbers[])
{
    int i,j,n;
    int temp=0;
    printf("int n = ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int b = numbers[0];
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            temp = numbers[j];
            numbers[j]=numbers[j+1];
            numbers[j+1]=temp;
        }
        numbers[9]=b;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",numbers[i]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int numbers[10];
    readValues(numbers);
    reverse(numbers);
    return 0;
}
```

My teacher is saying that reverse function is out of bound, but it is working fine for me. Please help.

Comment: Your homework is not more important than anyone else's question. Remove the screaming from the title.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: why is it URGENT? Note that the message this conveys is: You didnt bother to put effort into it when you had the time to do it. Now that it is urgent, why should we bother?

Comment: "Working fine for me" is the most common manifestation of undefined behaviour. Think about array indexing and  `j+1` for a few minutes.

Comment: First, as already said before me, it's not URGENT. Second,  inside your loop you access the "11th elemnt" when j equals 10 (due to the `numbers[j+1]` part).

Comment: its not a homework , it was a question for my exam , it has been given to every student to review it so that they can tell if any false deduction of marks has been done and the timeline is of 1 hr only , so please consider it

Comment: the timeline of 1 hour is for you to consider not for us. We can take as much time to answer your question as we like. Please try to understand

Comment: Just in case your teacher did not mention it, but the name `reverse` is a bad name for a function that is supposed to do some rotation of numbers.

Comment: its actually from feb , we just got it back ;-;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted in multiple comments your teacher is right - you access the array out of bounds - here:

```
    int b = numbers[0];
    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        temp = numbers[j];
        numbers[j]=numbers[j+1];
        numbers[j+1]=temp;
    }
    numbers[9]=b;
```

When `j` equals 9, the statement `numbers[j]=numbers[j+1];` turns into `numbers[9]=numbers[10];`. Reading `numbers[10]` is out of bounds.

> **... but it is working fine for me.**

It's undefined behavior so anything could happen. The reason that it appears to work for you is due to two things. 1) Reading `numbers[10]` didn't crash the program on your system  but just placed some unknown value in `numbers[9]` and 2) the statement `numbers[9]=b;` then placed the expected value in `numbers[9]`.

In other words - during program execution data was read out of bounds but later the correct value was placed at the destination so you never noticed it.

**BTW**

Why do you swap values in the loop? That isn't necessary. What you want is:

```
b = numbers[0];
numbers[0] = numbers[1];
numbers[1] = numbers[2];
...
numbers[8] = numbers[9];
numbers[9] = b;
```

So the code could simply be:

```
    int b = numbers[0];
    for(j=0;j<9;j++)    // Notice the 9 instead of 10
    {
        numbers[j]=numbers[j+1];
    }
    numbers[9]=b;
```

(or even use `memmove` instead of having a loop)

That said... why do the left shift one step at the time? Instead of doing that you can avoid the outer loop, i.e. `for(i=0;i<n;i++)`, and move the elements to the final position in one loop by shifting `n` steps directly.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation , but  sadly that means no marks ;-;

Answer (score 1):

Your loop using the `j` variable is accessing with numbers[j+1].
Double check your loop conditions.

Since this is homework, I will only give you a hint, not do it for you.

Comment: its not a homework, but for review . I have found a article related to it which also solve it through same way    https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c-program-for-program-for-array-rotation